# Site redirect to maintenance page after login

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller

The application that I am trying to run using Apache redirects to the maintenance page after submitting the login page.
The login form page: `acc/applicaion/views/login.php` appears fine with `action=site_url(login/user_login)`

**.htaccess:**
#

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /acc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /acc/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

#
It works fine locally.I am using codeIgnitor.I have tried clearing web cache but it could not solve the issue.
What can be the issue?

Comment: are you using any mvc framework ?

Comment: Maybe you have set maintenance mode in some Control Panel of server?

Comment: I am using codeIgnitor.

Comment: @Justinas I am not sure about maintenance mode in CPanel of server but  in that case  login page will also not appear?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear out your web cache?

Comment: Do you have any "Maintenance Mode Controller" on "codeignitor"(or you mean codeigniter)?
Note that some server Control Panel may have two types of maintenance mode controller, one for normal user and one for admin user.

Comment: if you are using codeIgniter, you may read the following: (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html)

Comment: I changed $config['index_page'] = '' to  $config['index_page'] = 'index.php' and action for login from site_url(login/user_login) to site_url(index.php/login/user_login) and it worked for a while.Now when I try to login site redirects to the login page again.

Answer (score 0):

I just enabled mod_rewrite.Now the application is working fine.